# Laravel User Model with two relationships to same Model

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a User model and an Events model. A User has_many Events (can create several events), and Events belong to User. However, since my Events also have a registration, I thought the best way would be to add a pivot table users_events_table that would contain all the registration, and now both Models pass to the belongs_to relationship.

Is there any way to maintain both relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you're probably after a [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship. It works similar to a belongs to many relationship except the pivot table is a first-class model, which means you can attach additional functionality to it. A user can have many events through registrations and vice-versa.

If you don't actually need that much additional information on the pivot table - maybe you just need `created_at`/`updated_at` timestamps then you can get away with [belongs to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and pop `withTimestamps()` on the end - Laravel will handle that for you. It does allow you to add more columns on that pivot table but they can get tricky to manage depending on you use case, which is where has many through might become a better solution.